# C - Payment Calc. not ending at $0

Tags: c, payment, calculator

I'm trying to create a payment calculator, however I am encountering an error in which the remaining balance is negative and not $0. Here is the code:

```
int main()
{
double selling, down, intRate, intBal, toBal, payment, loan, loanN, d;
int counter, i;

printf("Cost of item: ");
scanf("%lf", &selling);

printf("Down payment on item: ");
scanf("%lf", &down);

printf("Interest rate: ");
scanf("%lf", &intRate);

printf("Monthly payment: ");
scanf("%lf", &payment);

d= selling * 100.0;
i = d + 0.5;
selling = i / 100.0;

 d= down * 100.0;
i = d + 0.5;
down = i / 100.0;

 d= payment * 100.0;
i = d + 0.5;
payment = i / 100.0;

 counter = 1;

 loan = selling - down;

printf("--------------------------------------------------------------\n");
printf("Selling Price        = %8.2lf\n", selling);
printf("Down Payment         = %8.2lf\n", down);
 printf("Amount of Loan       = %8.2lf\n", loan);
 printf("Annual Interest Rate = %8.2lf\n", intRate);
printf("Monthly Payment      = %8.2lf\n", payment);
 printf("--------------------------------------------------------------\n");
 printf("Pay #  Old Balance  Payment  Interest  To Balance  New Balance\n");
 printf("-----  -----------  -------  --------  ----------  -----------\n");

 while (loan > 0)
 {
 if (loan < payment)
 {
    payment = loan + intBal;
 }
 printf("%5i  %11.2lf  %7.2lf  ", counter, loan, payment);
 intBal = intRate * loan / 12;
 printf("%8.2lf  ", intBal);
 toBal = payment - intBal;
 printf("%10.2lf  ", toBal);
 loanN = loan - toBal;
 loan = loanN;
 printf("%11.2lf\n", loanN);
 counter++;
 }
return 0;
```

Comment: What is the question, what did you try, what did you understood? Did you use a debugger to debug your program?

Comment: **Never use floating point to represent money**. In addition, please format (indent) your code correctly.

Comment: No, I did not use a debugger. The problem I am having is in the While loop. If the loan amount is 1000 with an interest of 0.18 down payment of 0 and monthly payment of 0, the end result should be $0 for the remaining balance - however it comes out to be -0.73. And no I did not use a debugger - I'm taking a basic programming course so I have not really been introduced to it although I do know its purpose.

Comment: @BrianRoach I see where your coming from but in the beginning of the program I rounded the numbers to the nearest cent. However, what number type do you recommend I use? I always format my code correctly - however I simply copied and pasted it into the text editor here that's how it came out.

Comment: Use an integral type, such as `int`. Calculate everything in cents and then convert to dollars and cents only at the output formatting stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're charging them twice for interest at the end of the loan.  Move this

```
if (loan < payment)
{
    payment = loan + intBal;
}
```

to after this line

```
intBal = intRate * loan / 12;
```

Comment: That's intentional; the bank has to make money somehow!  :-D

Comment: LOL, that's exactly what I thought, too.